# How do I modify my CSS so that I can display an element in the DOM with a specific color?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a website using Bootstrap and JavaScript. I am trying to learn how to implement a feature that will show that a user is actively engaging with the site by displaying a green bubble next to their profile name when they are logged into my web application. I have created the project and have included some code in an attempt to show the active user bubble in green instead of the red bubble that indicates the user is offline.

Please see the image below that displays what I am trying to accomplish.

I have also included a code snippet for clarity.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

[image]

**html**

```
 <div id="user-avtive"><span><img  src="/assets/images/signin/User-online.png"></span></div>
```

Comment: is there a specific problem? You've shown an image, and some HTML that could possibly produce that dot ...

Comment: Can you paste your complete code, both CSS, HTML, & JS to CodePen.io and share the link and I will help you solve it please?

Comment: @lopezdp sir, my project is a emebr js, i asked last week , anyone dont know how to make ir emebr js, but some one help me to fix it usinh html and js i can convert it ember, this is my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232757/ember-js-ember-paper-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of **pseudo elements** `::after,::before` instead of images.
You can try something like this.

```css
.user{
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
text-transform:uppercase;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}

.user::after{
content:"";
height:8px;
width:8px;
border-radius:50px;
background-color:#000000;
top:0;
right:-10px;
margin:auto;
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
}

.user.active::after{
background-color:#00ff00;
}

.user .username{
color:#0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="user active">
hi <span class="username">User</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, but I would use `border-radius: 50%` instead. Use 50% to make sure a circle is always rendered, regardless of what the width and height are.

Comment: yes even that can be used, i have faced problem before using percentages. so i used px here.